# IE10 random image rendering issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, image-rendering

I have a website which displays fine on all browsers (even lower versions of IE than IE10). But, on IE10, the images are having rendering issues like the screenshot attached below. If would have random colored bars on it at random times, but once refreshed it would be okay. I don't have any Javascripts on the page, just the styling to display the images. Any ideas? I tried googling and on StackOverflow but no luck. Do I need to put some sort of meta tags?

[image: IE10 Image not redering properly]

Comment: Does your browser have a full cache?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean full cache? It does have cache and I did empty it and tried, but no luck.

Comment: have you tried Compatibility View?

Comment: I'm guessing that this is only in IE10 on 1 single computer?? It looks like a problem reading from the cache. Try holding down the CTRL key and pressing F5. That should fully reload the page and you should no longer have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check about "Compatibility View" Option.

and why don't you try the edge meta tag?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```